# PayPal REST SDK not returning proper status on execute()

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I'm using the PayPal REST SDK to make a PayPal payment. When completing a purchase and calling the executePayment() method, the payment object's state isn't updating, and still says **created** instead of **approved**.

The payment goes through properly, and if I immediately look up the purchase after executing it, I get the expected approved state:

```
$paypal = new PayPal;
$payment = $paypal->executePayment($order_id, $payer_id);
echo $payment->getState(); // "created"

$lookup = Payment::get($order_id, getApiContext());
echo $lookup->getState(); // "approved"
```

(Here is the relevant method from the PayPal class..)

```
Class PayPal { 

    public function executePayment($paymentId, $payerId) 
    {
        $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, getApiContext());
        $paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution;
        $paymentExecution->setPayer_id($payerId);   
        $payment->execute($paymentExecution, getApiContext());  

        return $payment;
    }
}
```

On the PayPal pizza app, the [executePayment](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-php/blob/master/app/order/order_completion.php#L23-24) method works perfectly, and the returned Payment object shows a state of "approved" immediately..

```
$payment = executePayment($order['payment_id'], $_GET['PayerID']);
echo $payment->getState(); // "approved"
```

My executePayment() is [the exact, verbatim, code from the pizza app](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-php/blob/master/app/common/paypal.php#L156-164), the only difference is that I've put it into a class.

So what gives? Why would I not be getting "approved" back from the executePayment() method right away?

EDIT :

On further inspection, the PayPal pizza app is using rest-api-sdk-php v 0.6.* but the actual  rest api sdk, is on version 0.7.*

The Payment::execute() method has changed. In v0.6 it returns $this payment object like so:

```
class Payment extends PPModel implements IResource {
    ...
    public function execute( $payment_execution, $apiContext=null) {
        ...
        $json = $call->execute( array('PayPal\Rest\RestHandler'),
        $this->fromJson($json);
        return $this;       
    }
}
```

but now in v0.7 it's creating a new payment object and setting the values of the new object, which seems to not be working correctly..

```
class Payment extends PPModel implements IResource {
    ...
    public function execute( $payment_execution, $apiContext=null) {
        ...
        $ret = new Payment();
        $ret->fromJson($json);
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

So.. if you revert these changes to what they were in v0.6 instead of the $ret it works.. Not sure what the reasoning was for creating a new Payment(); object vs returning $this though.. maybe someone can enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind making the change in 0.7 was, the status you were getting before was because of a bug.

When you do a get Payment, you get a payment object. And previously, when you run execute, it was filling the object again, without resetting it. Because of that, you were able to do a getStatus, but that was not returned in Execute method. It was already there when you did a get call.

I hope this helps you understand the change.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a problem with the paypal sandbox not completing the order.

I was able to fix this problem without modifying the paypal api code.

- Login to the sandbox account for the xxx-facilitator@xxx account.
- click the menu item > profile - Update Email
- click 'confirm', it says already confirmed but now it works.

also make sure on the developer option 'Review test payments before they're completed.' is set to off.